# "Runner" contains entitlements that aren't in the entitlements file

Tags: flutter, codemagic

My project can be built for iOS without any problem. But on codemagic I get the following message:

Provisioning profile "my profile information" for "Runner" contains entitlements that aren't in the entitlements file: com.apple.developer.coremedia.hls.low-latency and com.apple.developer.healthkit.background-delivery. To use these entitlements, add them to your entitlements file. Otherwise, remove unused entitlements from your provisioning profile. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

I never use something from the healthkit and I don't know the other entitlement. How can I delete those and from where?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your provisioning profile has certain entitlements enabled and the entitlements aren't really in use.

To see what entitlements you have enabled, go to your developer account and under 'Profiles' you can see what capabilities you have listed. Or just go to Capabilties under Target in Xcode.

Check that against the Runner.entitlements file inside project/Runner

Remove capabilities that you are not using.

Read more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/diagnosing_issues_with_entitlements